# Map an Element from G1 to Zn in JPBC

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I am working with bilinear maps in project ORUTA and I have stuck at one equation while implementing it. The equation is:

```
r*h(λ)
```

where r is random element from Zn (for some large prime n) and λ is member of G1 where G1 is a multiplicative cyclic group with generator g.
here h() is given by G -> Zn.
How can I map value of λ which belongs to G1 to a value in Zn.

I am using JPBC library in java for implementing this pairing based application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need three things for that:

- a mapping function (element in G<sub>1</sub> to `byte[]`),
- actual cryptographic hash (`byte[]` to `byte[]`) and
- a mapping function (`byte[]` to element in Z<sub>n</sub>).

You can map any element to `byte[]` by encoding it like this (it doesn't matter what you do here as long as you are consistent):

```
byte[] g1Bytes = g1Element.toCanonicalRepresentation();
```

You can hash something with `java.security.MessageDigest`:

```
MessageDigest hasher = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
byte[] znBytes = hasher.digest(g1Bytes);
```

You can map some bytes to an element using the `pairing` (instance of `it.unisa.dia.gas.jpbc.Pairing`) and the appropriate field:

```
Element znElement = pairing.getZr().newElementFromHash(znBytes, 0, znBytes.length);
```